# Install older version of MongoDB with Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have this:

```
docker run -d --name my-name mongo
```

Does anyone know how to run a specific version with Docker?

something like:

```
docker run -d --name my-name mongo=2.4.9
```

I need to run mongo with version 2.4.9...

Comment: have you tried apt-get install package=version ?

Comment: My requirements changed, I need to put MongoDB in a separate container, but still need a specific version, see updated question

Comment: @AlexanderMills added info to the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install any mongodb version using mongodb repo.

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-10gen=2.4.9
```

**EDIT:**

You can also start mongodb container from an image with the exact version from their public docker hub repo.

Just choose the version that they have there:

```
curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/mongo/tags | jq '.[] | (.name)' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

And start your mongodb docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -d --name my-name mongo:<version>
```

p.s. As far as we can see there are only following `2.4.x` available versions of images on mongodb public docker hub repo:

> ```
> 2.4
> 2.4.10
> 2.4.11
> 2.4.12
> 2.4.13
> 2.4.14
> ```

Comment: This is a picture-book answer! Thank you!